# Microsoft Graph API python SDK ,creating a enterprise application

Tags: python, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

After following [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/application-saml-sso-configure-api?tabs=python%2Cpowershell-script](https://stackoverflow.com) I'm trying to build a Enterprise Application .

However code block mentions

```
graph_client = GraphServiceClient(credentials, scopes)

request_body = InstantiatePostRequestBody(
    display_name = "AWS Contoso",
)

result = await graph_client.application_templates.by_application_template_id('applicationTemplate-id').instantiate.post(request_body)
```

There is no clue to understand how to import **InstantiatePostRequestBody method**
Please can anyone will be able to help

tried randomly importing different packages to test if any of then had InstantiatePostRequestBody method to no avail

Comment: I suspect that's just a placeholder  You're just creating something to pass to `instantiate.post`.  Does it work if you just create a simple dictionary?

Comment: tested and No it doesnot work with a simple dictionary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`InstantiatePostRequestBody`](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-python/blob/main/msgraph/generated/application_templates/item/instantiate/instantiate_post_request_body.py#L8-L47) is available as part of the [Microsoft Graph Python SDK](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-python/).

```
from msgraph.generated.application_templates.item.instantiate.instantiate_post_request_body import InstantiatePostRequestBody
```

I'm not sure if the lack of documentation is somehow intentional and/or indicative that this isn't supposed to be used directly this way.

Comment: Thank you very much for linking the SDK hyperlink as well. This details is not very clear in the documentation and was very much lost following the official documentation,. I think as you pointed out searching the github repo is the best way to find how to import a method given in the microsoft documentation